# Retrieve data from json file and print the result in ion-list view

Tags: json, ionic-framework, ionic2

My json code is presented.

```
{"samples":[
{"Date" : "Thursday 16 Mar", "Data1" : "Sample Child","Data2" : "Sample Class","Date" : "6:29 pm", "image1" : "E:\Event\www\img\img2.jpg", "text" : "Tiger Tale", "image2" : "E:\Event\www\img\img5.jpg" }
{"Date" : "Tuesday 14 Mar", "Data1" : "Sample Child","Data2" : "Sample Class","Date" : "12:43 pm", "image1" : "E:\Event\www\img\img6.jpg", "text" : "Tiger Tale", "image2" : "E:\Event\www\img\img4.jpg" }
{"Date" : "Friday 10 Mar","Data1" : "Sample Child","Data2" : "Sample Class","Date" : "12:03 pm", "image1" : "E:\Event\www\img\img1.jpg", "text" : "Tiger Tale", "image2" : "E:\Event\www\img\img4.jpg" }
```

Comment: Assume your json data in a variable name `jsonData`. Now define an array `data: Array<any>`. then `data  = jsonData.samples`. Now you can use `data` array for [ion-list](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#lists).

Comment: I am pretty new to ionic so I want to know how do I retreive the data from json file to my blank app in ionic and display in ion-list view

Comment: In that case see [ionic-conference-app](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app). In [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/src/providers/conference-data.ts) you can see how they retrieve data from a json file.

Comment: so to access the elements in json do I use data[1].Date in ion-list

Comment: Something like `<ion-item *ngFor="let item of data">item.Date</ion-item>` or `<ion-item *ngFor="let i in data">data[i].Date</ion-item>` in angular.
In ts `for(let item of data ) console.log(item.Date)` or `for(let i in data ) console.log(data[i].Date)`

Answer (score 0):

your typescript file:

```
yourData = {
"samples":[
 {"Date" : "Thursday 16 Mar", "Data1" : "Sample Child","Data2" : "Sample       Class","Date" : "6:29 pm", "image1" : "E:\Event\www\img\img2.jpg", "text" : "Tiger Tale", "image2" : "E:\Event\www\img\img5.jpg" }
{"Date" : "Tuesday 14 Mar", "Data1" : "Sample Child","Data2" : "Sample Class","Date" : "12:43 pm", "image1" : "E:\Event\www\img\img6.jpg", "text" : "Tiger Tale", "image2" : "E:\Event\www\img\img4.jpg" }
{"Date" : "Friday 10 Mar","Data1" : "Sample Child","Data2" : "Sample Class","Date" : "12:03 pm", "image1" : "E:\Event\www\img\img1.jpg", "text" : "Tiger Tale", "image2" : "E:\Event\www\img\img4.jpg" }]
}

listData = yourData.samples;

//component template\templateURL:
<ion-list *ngFor="let item of listData">
 <ion-item>
  {{item.Data1}}
  {{item.text}}
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: I am pretty new to ionic so I want to know how do I retreive the data from json file to my blank app in ionic and display in ion-list view

Comment: Check out this example which walks you through how to consume json data in ionic 2 app, assuming that you would want to consume a hosted api\service: https://www.joshmorony.com/using-http-to-fetch-remote-data-from-a-server-in-ionic-2/

Answer (score 0):

check this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/bYpCQIpFXh7y8PteGInZ?p=preview)

insert this code in constructor

```
this.samples = [
 {"Date" : "Thursday 16 Mar", "Data1" : "Sample Child","Data2" : "Sample       Class","Date" : "6:29 pm", "image1" : "E:\Event\www\img\img2.jpg", "text" : "Tiger Tale", "image2" : "E:\Event\www\img\img5.jpg" }
{"Date" : "Tuesday 14 Mar", "Data1" : "Sample Child","Data2" : "Sample Class","Date" : "12:43 pm", "image1" : "E:\Event\www\img\img6.jpg", "text" : "Tiger Tale", "image2" : "E:\Event\www\img\img4.jpg" }
{"Date" : "Friday 10 Mar","Data1" : "Sample Child","Data2" : "Sample Class","Date" : "12:03 pm", "image1" : "E:\Event\www\img\img1.jpg", "text" : "Tiger Tale", "image2" : "E:\Event\www\img\img4.jpg" }]
```

and use `ngFor`in html

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of samples">
  {{item.Data1}}
  {{item.text}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```